# How to horizontally center text in a TMemo component?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

I have a TMemo component in my Delphi application.

How would I horizontally center the text within the component so that everything is in the middle?

Answer (score 5):

Simply set the memo's `Alignment` property to `taCenter`.

[image: A VCL TMemo control with its text centred.]